# Update recycler view adapter on Observable emission

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, android-recyclerview

While working on chat application a necessity of image handling - its download and upload - has been faced. Handling itself is done with help of Observables of RxJava2; while commands for downloads or uploads are done from OnBindViewHolder() of RecyclerView Adapter.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (currentlyUsedPositionToMessageMap.containsKey(position)) {
        val message = currentlyUsedPositionToMessageMap[position]
        when (message) {
            is TextMessage -> (holder as TextMessageViewHolder).bind(message)
            is ImageMessage -> (holder as ImageMessageViewHolder).bind(message)
        }
    } else {
        val (messageType, downloadableMessage) = downloadableMessages[position]

        disposables += downloadableMessage                    //Observable
            .subscribeBy(
                onNext = {
                    currentlyUsedPositionToMessageMap[position] = it
                    notifyItemChanged(position)
                },
                onError = {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(it))
                }
            )

        when (messageType){
            "image" -> (holder as ImageMessageViewHolder).showDefaultAnimation()
            "text" -> (holder as TextMessageViewHolder).showDefaultAnimation()
        }
    }
}
```

**The idea for code above is:** if image(or text) has been already downloaded fill in ViewHolder with data else set download task and make ViewHolder show some default animation.

**Problem faced:** no ability to update visible ViewHolders after downloaded task has been done because notifyItemChanged(position) causes following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

So, how can I resolve this Exception? In other words, **how can I update ViewHolder at [position] (if it is visible) after successful Image download with downloaded Image?**

Answer (score 0):

### What happened? In short:

Update was done on not completely loaded RecyclerView what led to the Exception:

**Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling**

Note: "**this method**" referring to notifyItemChanged(position) for item update

---

### Elaboration:

Issue was related not to Imaage handing but to Text handling. Application design was that if current Item is a downloadable Image then go for its download; if it is already cached Text then return new Observable with the text from Android Main Thread. So, creation on main thread of Observable raced with RecyclerView ViewHolder data filling. Thus, when Observable was returned, RecyclerView was not loaded with all the items that it must be loaded in other time what led to update operation executed on not complete RecyclerView. Hence, the exception!